# Where should I be storing extra strings for Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site with a theme.  But now I need to extend it.

For example, I want to make a custom section on the homepage.  The section needs a header which is not a part of any post.  I know how to code this, but I don't see where I should be storing the string which will be displayed.

Possible solutions:

1. Store in the PHP file itself, obviously not a good idea.
2. Store in the database as an option, using

   get_option( 'my_custom_header', 'default_value' );

   The issue with this is that there is no easy way to edit the value other than opening up the database directly.
3. Use an options plug in.  The ones I have seen seem an overkill.
4. Write my own so I have a table specifically for such tables.

So the question is what is the best place to be storing such strings?

Greg

Comment: Read http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was extending the existing theme options panel to add a few extra options.